# MVCC_READ_CONFLICT error when update the fabric chaincode with composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I use composer deployed to the fabric network with five peers.
Today when i try to update the fabric chaincode with composer bna file.
but one peer return error:

```
Error: Peer localhost:13051 has rejected transaction '39ae7b9cf735ca56a7b9a20c60745206d94852a0a4f73d14cd6fd8813ef57566' with code MVCC_READ_CONFLICT
```

althrough the new dev* chaincode docker of this peer is generated an up.
but,all the transaction will return:

```
 EXPIRED CHAINCODE
```

so i check this peer's log, found it still use the older version chaincode.

so if there is somehow to update this peer' chaincode version?
 could bna chaincode generated by composer using node.js  be use directly by fabric?

Comment: What version of fabric are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has happened is you have a state fork and as such peers are going to disagree (and they disagree on the version of chaincode to use). Fabric 1.4 (not sure which micro version) introduced commands to reset peers back to previous block numbers which you could try to use to reset your problem peer(s) back to a point where they were in agreement and let them pull the blocks from the orderer again. 
If not, then you will have to remove that problem peer(s) from your network and create new peers and join them to the channel.

Comment: Do you mean the "peer node rollback"? It 's supported from v1.4. After rollback, peers  will receive blocks from order, so will the chaincode version will be agreed? The info of chaincode version is also stored in tx in block? In this situation, only peer X needs to be rollback?

Comment: there is a rollback and a reset I believe. If peer X is the only one disagreeing then that would seem like the sensible choice.

Comment: Is there a flexible approach to do the same thing on peer with fabric v1.1 as peer reset action on peer with v1.4, eg,like remove the peer data ?@david_k

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry but that doesn't mean to say there isn't one. I guess you could look at what the peer reset command does by looking at the source code and see if you can recreate it manually on a 1.1 system

Comment: What happened in this situation leading to a state fork?