# The mismatch of chaincode verison within fabric peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In this situation:

```
1,Peer X is down
2,Other peer perform upgrade of chaincode with success
3,Peer X is up, it will receive block and tx from the order/other peers, but it lacks of the newest version of chaincode.
4,In my try, if update the chaincode on peer X, it will result to mismatch of the version within peers
```

How to make all peer have the same verison of chaincode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the last version of the chaincode in all the endorser peers. Always. The admin of each organization should do that, to be accurate.

Install it in every endorser peer and instantiate/upgrade once.

Be sure that you have the same version in every peer by comparing:

```sh
md5sum /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mychaincode.1.0
```

Comment: Could i remove all data(ledger  and so on) of peer X , and restart peer X, intend to receive the chaincode and tx from other peer/order,  is this workable?

Comment: If you clear the ledger and restart, your peer (once joined again to the channel) is going to synchronize the ledger with the channel, but it is not going to install the chaincode by itself. So that is not the solution. You must install the same chaincode (same name, version number and sources) in each endorser peer. Better package (and distribute) the chaincode before installing instead of installing from source.

Comment: So if there is mismatch of chaincode within peers already, how ?only way to remove the peer X from fabric network?

Comment: Enter into the peer container whose chaincode mismatch the instantiated one, remove `/var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mychaincode.1.0`, exit and install the correct one. Or install a new version in every peer and upgrade the version.

Comment: I have tried the mentioned method, but the upgrade failed with MVCC_READ_CONFLICT on the peer X

Comment: what version of fabric are you running ?

Comment: see my response to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884889/mvcc-read-conflict-error-when-update-the-fabric-chaincode-with-composer

Comment: Thanks@david_k  It‘s sadly with fabric 1.1, i have remove the peer X