# what situation will lead the fabric network to a state fork

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a question about in what situation it will lead the fabric network to a state fork?
I had met the state fork, see [The mismatch of chaincode verison within fabric peers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60944381/the-mismatch-of-chaincode-verison-within-fabric-peers) and [MVCC_READ_CONFLICT error when update the fabric chaincode with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884889/mvcc-read-conflict-error-when-update-the-fabric-chaincode-with-composer), but I am not very certain about the reason. The offline peer will receive the txs and blocks from the orders and other peers when it is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working correctly, Fabric should never experience a state fork.  Seeing MVCC_READ_CONFLICTS, or failed chaincode updates usually does *not* indicate a state fork.  The easiest way to check for a state fork is to compare the commit hash.  Look for a message in your log of the format:

`"[%s] Committed block [%d] with %d transaction(s) in %dms (state_validation=%dms block_and_pvtdata_commit=%dms state_commit=%dms) commitHash=[%x]"`

For the same block on the same channel, compare this across your peers.  If the value is the same, then you have no state fork, if it is different, then you may need to refer to the 'reset' documentation linked in your question.

To directly answer you question how can Fabric produce a state fork?

There was [a bug](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-9776) where in certain error cases from couchDB Fabric could inappropriately mark a transaction as invalid, when it was in fact a DB read error.  This bug has been fixed since [this commit in the release-1.1 stream](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/8bc324551efa887d38000b226500d0a084a8b0f4).

Alternatively, the statedb could become corrupted for external reasons, for instance, failing to fsync properly, such as enabling couchdb's [delayed commits](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/couchdb.html#couchdb/delayed_commits) feature.

If you are running an up to date version of Fabric, and you are able to reproduce any sort of state forking scenario, the developers would be very happy to receive a bug report so that the issue can be fixed.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer in detail. Yes  I encountered  the state fork  from the bug in v1.1.0  ,and the statedb corrupted too. By the way, a transaction's state as invalid marked  by a peer will be synchronized to other peers and marked as invalid in those peers?@Jason Yellick

Comment: If one peer is forked,is  it  ok to use an early backup version of this peer ,somehow like the rollback cmd, intending to receive the new txs and blocks from order?@Jason Yellick

Comment: And the statedb could become corrupted yet , for example, System OOM, how to eliminate this influence in new version fabric？

Comment: A system OOM should not result in a state fork.  Fabric performs a safe commit (ie, writes intent to commit to persistent storage, performs the commit, records that the commit occurred on persistent storage), so that if the process crashes at any point, for any reason, it should still be able to recover and resume commit at the correct point.  This is a standard technique in databases, including couchdb and leveldb, so OOM or other crashes should not produce a state fork.  Again, if you can produce a state fork via a crash, please report it, it is a bug and should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks,but the v1.1.2 tag had been removed, so how could I check the commits and learn how the bug be fixed.@ Jason Yellick

Comment: I've edited the answer to point to the exact commit which fixed the bug in the release-1.1 stream.